# authenticate users in smtp relay server exim4

Tags: linux, smtp, exim, e-mailrelay

I'm configuring relay SMTP server for sending email alerts from my local network. I need to send emails alerts from services witch run on my servers. And I need to authenticate it: each service should have its own virtual email address and SMTP server should relay email from authenticated services only. I have no idea how to do it. I tried use exim4 + dovecot and it failed. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Why did you attempt dovecot?